# Правильное использование retrofit

Tags: java, android

Вообщем, нашел в сети такой пример:
[ретрофит](http://blog.zacorp.ru/mobile/ispolzovanie-retrofit-v-vashem-android-prilozhenii/)

при подключение возникли следующие трудности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибка 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите,что не так я делаю?

интерфейс:

```
public interface GithubAPI {
@GET("/users/{username}")
Call<GithubUser> getUser(@Path("username") String username);

@GET("/users/{username}")
Call<GithubUser> getId(@Path("id") int id);
```

}

Comment: У вас как минимум нет класса ```GitResult```. Ну и аннотацию ```Generated``` можно убрать.

Comment: @ temq 3 
не очень удачный примре...но решил попробовать
а что тогда у service  client не подхватывает?